# How to extend the Spartacus PLP page

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In Spartacus PLP page, I am trying to extend PLP page.
Below is module and ts code

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        CMSProductGridComponent: {
          component: ProductsGridComponent
        }
      }
    } as CmsConfig)
```

In ts file
export class ProductsGridComponent extends ProductGridItemComponent{}

**Issue**
The OOTB search call is not happening. When I comment the override in module file OOTB search API is happening. Is there any mistake for extend PLP page ?
Can any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CategoryPageMetaResolver. It seems you might have to override the hasProductListComponent check:

- You need to create a service that extends CategoryPageMetaResolver.
- Override hasProductListComponent so that it will identify your
  ProductsGridComponent as a 'ProductListComponent'.
- Provide the service in a module -
  {provide:CategoryPageMetaResolver,useClass:MyCategoryPageMetaResolver}.